# What is the difference between build:android and build:android -t apk?

Tags: javascript, build, expo

I'm trying to publish an app, and the docs say,

```
# Start the build:
Run expo build:android or expo build:ios
```

Literally on the next line, without any explanation it says,

```
# If you choose to build for Android
When building for android you can choose to build APK (expo build:android -t apk)
```

No where does it explain the difference. Which should I use when I want to build an android app for the Google Play Store?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/):

> When building for android you can choose to build APK (expo build:android -t apk) or Android App Bundle (expo build:android -t app-bundle). App bundles are recommended, but you have to make sure the Google Play App Signing is enabled for your project, you can read more about it here

I am guessing the -t signifies something internally for Expo as you can see it also is being used for the app-bundle variant and the apk (and also for iOS builds).

Depending on what you want, either use:

- `expo build:android -t apk`

or

- `expo build:android -t app-bundle`

To read more about Application Bundles, go [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

Comment: I've read the documentation. I'm asking what the difference is between `expo build:android` and `expo build:android -t apk`

Comment: @MikeK - as it says in the documentation, running ```expo build:android``` will create a packager for your project (first time run). As it states, there are two ways to upload your application to the google play store (which I have explained in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, `expo build:android` is the *same* as `expo build:android -t apk`
since the default value of the `-t` option is `apk`